# Cronjob that optimizes and cleans all mysql databases

Tags: php, debian, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job that everyday optmizes the mysql database using debian on a virtual machine.

First I have tried using the mysqlcheck like this:

```
0 * * * * mysqlcheck -Aao –auto-repair -u root -p[password] > /dev/null
```

I got this error: **mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect**

after googling this error I found Dave Stoddard [Comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html#c9504) who was experiencing the same problem:

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf --all-databases --auto-repair 2>&1 | grep -v "OK" | mail -s "Database Problem" root
```

or `0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf --all-databases --auto-repair 2>&1 | grep -v "OK" | mail -s "Database Problem" root`

Error from above:

```
/bin/sh: root: command not found
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/mysqlcheck: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Would I be better to create a cronjob which access this PHP script: http://www.webdigity.com/index.php?action=tutorial;code=16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seriously, you might over-doing,
your approach will causing some unnecessary table lock,
which mean it easily freezing your application that required database access

the optimization is required only when the table is too fragmented 
meaning contains free-space,
an optimization able to impact the index key and data file

**what is free-space?**

this query will return list of table need to be optimized

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.tables 
where data_free>0;
```

build using a simple bash script

```
chk="select concat(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.', TABLE_NAME) from information_schema.tables where data_free>0;"

for tbl in $(mysql -u root -pxxx -N <<< $chk)
do
  mysql -u xxx -pxxx -N <<< "optimize table $tbl"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The two errors are pretty clear... The first one says that root@localhost is not permitted access to the database - either you're using the wrong password, or the root account in MySQL (which is usually present by default) has been removed.

The mail error is typical of using `mail` on the different systems - standard GNU mail  (from GNU mailutils 1.2) has a -E option to execute a command, which your mail command is lacking. Check `man mail` to see if the option has a different name on your system.

Comment: I double checked that the root users password is correct the comment from Dave explains why I get this error.

I will check test without the mail -E option

Comment: I have edited the question with the new error I am now receiving via email